# Java - Adding single string to start of array

Tags: java, android, arrays

This is for an android project. I'm using an array to build a spinner which all works fine. However I'm now trying to add a record to the start of the array so that no option is selected when the page loads.

I'm trying to just use an `myarray.add("---")` type thing but it falls over with the following error:

```
11-05 10:50:36.995: D/AndroidRuntime(16763): Shutting down VM
11-05 10:50:36.995: W/dalvikvm(16763): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412b42a0)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAsset.updateLocalDesc(AddAsset.java:461)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAsset$3.onItemSelected(AddAsset.java:262)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-05 10:50:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(16763):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 10:50:37.020: D/dalvikvm(16763): GC_CONCURRENT freed 243K, 7% free 12989K/13831K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 25ms
```

My code is:

```
 public void setupAssetType(Boolean beenSet){
         Log.e("CamDebug", "Loading asset type");
           Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from AssetTypes", null);  
           Log.e("Error Tracking", "Loading AssetTypes");
           if(c.getCount() != 0) {
             c.moveToFirst();
             final ArrayList<String> mAssetType = new ArrayList<String>();
             final ArrayList<String> mTypeID= new ArrayList<String>();


               c.moveToFirst();
               mAssetType.add("TEST");
               mTypeID.add("TEST");
               while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
                    mAssetType.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AssetType")));
                    mTypeID.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AssetTypeID")));
                    c.moveToNext();
               }

                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mAssetType);
                spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
                spnAssetType.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                int count = 0;
                if(beenSet == true) {
                    for (String mID : mTypeID) {

                        Log.e("Set asset type", mID);
                        if(mID.equals(orAssetTypeID)){
                            spnAssetType.setSelection(count);
                            Log.e("Set asset type FOUND", mID);
                            break;
                        }
                        count++;
                        }   
                    }
                    c.close();            
                spnAssetType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                     Log.e("CamDebug", "Selected asset type");
                        if(mAssetType.size() > 0){
                            setupGroup(mTypeID.get(position), false);   
                            AssetType = mTypeID.get(position);
                            updateLocalDesc();
                            Log.e("Error Tracking", "Before Asset Type set");
                            if(mTypeID.get(position) != null) {
                                AssetTypeID = mTypeID.get(position);
                                } else {
                                    AssetTypeID = "";
                                }
                            Log.e("Error Tracking", "After As");
                        }   
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

                }

            });

           }
    }
```

As you can see I've added:

```
mAssetType.add("TEST");
mTypeID.add("TEST");
```

to test. But it's not working. Any ideas will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Line 461 is:  `AssetGroup = spnAssetGroup.getSelectedItem().toString();`

**EDIT 2** - Please don't downvote without saying why. It's not productive what so ever

**EDIT 3** This seems to be where the error is coming in. This block includes the like 461 and is used to create text from the text spinners to a single line:

```
public void updateLocalDesc(){

    AssetType = spnAssetType.getSelectedItem().toString();
    AssetGroup = spnAssetGroup.getSelectedItem().toString();

   if(spnAssetSubGroup.getSelectedItem() != null && !spnAssetSubGroup.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")){
       AssetSubGroup = spnAssetSubGroup.getSelectedItem().toString();
       tbLongDescription.setText(AssetType + "-" + AssetGroup + "-" + AssetSubGroup);
   } else
   {
       tbLongDescription.setText(AssetType + "-" + AssetGroup);
   }

}
```

Comment: Which line is line 461 in your code?

Comment: where is method updateLocalDesc(). and what is line 461 in Assets class.

Comment: remove final for both ArrayList and make both class level variables

Comment: I can't see the `line 461` that you have pointed out in your code.

Comment: either `spnAssetGroup` is `null` or `spnAssetGroup.getSelectedItem()` returns `null`. (Your NPE is thrown in `com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAsset.updateLocalDesc(AddAsset.java:461)` and you show us the method `setupAssetType`)

Comment: i don't see spnAssetGroup.getSelectedItem() in this code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. When I was passing nothing in to the array, the second cursor was coming back as 0. So when it tried to set the text for the description area, it was null and empty so doing:

```
public void updateLocalDesc(){

    if(spnAssetType.getSelectedItem() != null){
          AssetType = spnAssetType.getSelectedItem().toString(); 
    } else {
        AssetType = " ";
    }

    if(spnAssetGroup.getSelectedItem() != null){
        AssetGroup = spnAssetGroup.getSelectedItem().toString();
    } else {
        AssetGroup = " ";
    }
   AssetType = spnAssetType.getSelectedItem().toString();     


       if(spnAssetSubGroup.getSelectedItem() != null && !spnAssetSubGroup.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")){
           AssetSubGroup = spnAssetSubGroup.getSelectedItem().toString();
           tbLongDescription.setText(AssetType + "-" + AssetGroup + "-" + AssetSubGroup);
       } else
       {
           tbLongDescription.setText(AssetType + "-" + AssetGroup);
       }

}
```

Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that line 461 is

```
mAssetType.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("AssetType")));
```

and the NullPointer must be coming from

```
c.getString()
```

Check the  [android javadocs of cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29)

If the column is not found c.getColumnIndex("AssetType") will return -1 causing c.getString() to throw a NullPointerException.

You should break that line into 3 lines and debug it to exactly find the problem.

Comment: @Tom Good if its working, but did you figure out why? Can't really understand much the way you've given the code now.